# Bluetooth Low Energy, Gatt, UWP, read, write notify application

Tags: .net, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on a UWP BLE application and my device is a wahoo kickr Fan which increase its fan speed according to the heart rate,
I am trying to crack the fan and I am writing the values to increase of decrease the speed of fan.
It has write without response Flag.
The first value 0x04,0x04 is to turn on the device and the 0x02, 0x64 is for increasing speed.
When i write the value 0x04, 0x04 it is only written once and the rest of speed increasing values are not writing on the device.it passes the values but nothing change.

But when i keep turn on the fan at the speed of 1 and i send the parameters of 0x02 OP code for speed ,0x64 (speed value) then the speed changes.

I need to know if it is possible to write the values one after another.
I have also tried delay or sleep method.

It turns on the fan but the rest of the speed values are written and the concsole message is displyed but nothing happens to the speed of the fan.

```
else if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.WriteWithoutResponse))

{

Console.WriteLine($"\t\t[{characteristic.Uuid}] write without response property found");

var writer = new DataWriter();
writer.WriteByte(0x04); //op code to access turning on
writer.WriteByte(0x04); //value to turn on device
                                            
GattCommunicationStatus resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

if (resultWrite == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Turned on");
                                               
 }
                                            
 writer = new DataWriter();
 writer.WriteByte(0x02);  //op code to set the speed
 writer.WriteByte(0x64);  // the speed value 
 resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());
 if (resultWrite == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("speed increased to max level");
  }

}
```

Comment: It looks like the BLE device only accept one command in one time. Do you have other bluetooth device to test? Also, please collect the bluetooth trace about this using [busiotools](https://github.com/Microsoft/busiotools/tree/master/bluetooth/tracing).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, yes the device accepts one command at a time. 
I have other devices like indoor bike trainer i am also working on that.

Comment: I am new to BLE and i don't know how to use the Bluetooth trace.
I am also tried it on RaspberryPi which is ok where you have to enter command manually after one is processed but i want to try it on the code unfortunatley i have to run it again and again to write values to change the behavior of the device.

Comment: The github link I shared contains the tutorials about how to use the blusio tool to collect the BLE logs.

Comment: **GattCommunicationStatus resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(), GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse);**



------>so it was done, the thing was you have to notify the server about the value is written by adding. 


 **GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse**

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please Go ahead and post your solution and accept it. This could help others who are facing the same issue.